# How do I get child of a snap without knowing the key in firebase and firebase-admin

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I have a queue in my database that looks like this:

```
server
  queue
    -RANDOM_ID_1234
      active: "true"
      text: "Some text"
    -RANDOM_ID_5678
      active: "false"
      text: "Another text"
    -RANDOM_ID_91011
      active: "false"
      text: "Text that does not matter"
```

I want to query and get the active item:

```
queueRef.orderByChild('active').equalTo('true').once('value', function(snap) {
  if (snap.exists()) {
    console.log(snap.val());
  }
});
```

`console.log` will return something like:

```
{
  -RANDOM_ID_1234: {
      active: "true"
      text: "Some text"
  }
}
```

How do I get the text without knowing the key?

I used lodash (see my answer below), but there must be a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

A Firebase Snapshot has a built-in way to iterate its children:

```
queueRef.orderByChild('active').equalTo('true').once('value', function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
    console.log(child.key+": "+child.val());
  }
});
```

Comment: Would be awesome if there was something like `getChildAtIndex(0)` or array notation `[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

I use lodash and get the key like this:

```
/* 
 *  I get the keys of the object as array 
 *  and take the first one.
 */
const key = _.first(_.keys(snap.val()));
```

And then get the text from the snap like this:

```
/* 
 *  then I create a path to the value I want 
 *  using the key.
 */
const text= snap.child(`${key}/text`).val();
```